# Access-Control-Allow-Origin - localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, http-headers

I have problems with receiving json through ajax, the error is below. According to the information I've found so far regarding the error this seems to be some kind of cross domain issue, but I have no idea of what that means and how to solve it.

There may be an issue with the response header (I have created the API myself and have no experiences since before), however a 200 OK is received if accessing the url directly in the browser.

If accessing the url directly in the browser valid json is shown, so that shouldn't be the problem.

How can this be solved?

**Note: The url goes to an Apache server, not a file that has been the case for 95% of the questions here on Stack that I've read about the issue.**

### Error in inspector:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/api/v1/products?_=1355583847077.
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Error: error
```

### The code:

```
    $.ajaxSetup ({
      url: "http://localhost/api/v1/products", // <--- returns valid json if accessed in the browser
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      contentType: "application/json"
    })
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data){

            console.log("You made it!");
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
           console.log("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
       }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

### Params

_   1355583610778

### Headers

**Response Headers:**

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  3887
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Sat, 15 Dec 2012 14:50:53 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.1
```

**Request Headers:**

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0
```

### Response

Nothing here...

Comment: are you trying to access from different protocol like `https` , a different port or a subdomain?

Comment: holyredbeard, on your point about the url going to an Apache server not a file, I wonder if you are not aware of the difference between "absolute" and "relative" URLs. After some background reading, I think you will find that what you think are "file" requests, are actually actually requests to the same server that served the current page. I'm guessing that the absence of "http://..." is confusing you.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Ok, so if I put up the API live on a server this problem would probably go away, if I get you right?

Comment: You should certainly try serving `api/v1/products` from the same server that serves the original page - this is a conventional single-domain single-server model, adopted by the majority of web sites. I can't say for certain whether or not this will fix the problem but it will definitely eliminate cross-domain issues as a source of the bug.

Comment: server can certainly be on localhost... but must be same domain as page you are sending AJAX request from

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try and implement some form of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) mechanism. If you're using PHP it could be something as simple as this...

```
/* If a callback has been supplied then prepare to parse the callback
 ** function call back to browser along with JSON. */
$jsonp = false;
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'callback' ] ) ) {
    $_GET[ 'callback' ] = strip_tags( $_GET[ 'callback' ] );
    $jsonp              = true;

    $pre  = $_GET[ 'callback' ] . '(';
    $post = ');';
} //isset( $_GET[ 'callback' ] )

/* Encode JSON, and if jsonp is true, then ouput with the callback
 ** function; if not - just output JSON. */
$json = json_encode( /* data here */ );
print( ( $jsonp ) ? $pre . $json . $post : $json );
```

All this would do is check for a `$_GET` var called *callback*, and then wrap the output in a function call - taking the `$_GET['callback']` name as a function name.

Then your AJAX call becomes something like this...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/* script here */ ', 
  data: /* data here - if any */,
  contentType: "jsonp", // Pay attention to the dataType/contentType
  dataType: 'jsonp', // Pay attention to the dataType/contentType
  success: function (json) {
    /* call back */
  }
});
```

When jQuery is given `'jsonp'` as a dataType/contentType it will take care of providing a callback function name for you - and setting the callback function up etc; meaning you don't have to do anything really!

**From the jQuery documentation:**

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

In closing; JSONP is going to be your best bet - I've included PHP code in the off chance that your server side script is using PHP; if not then the principles are the same. The jQuery/client side stuff stays the same regardless of server side technologies though. (*in general*)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks alot for this descriptive answer. I have implemented the solution, however it's still errors. :/ This is what errorThrown tells me in the browser: "Error: jQuery18308595284975599498_1355591723832 was not called"

Comment: That would suggest that the server isn't returning JSONP, but still returning plain JSON. :/ How did you implement the JSONP solution server-side? If possible, open the ```http://localhost/api/v1/products``` file in your browser and see what it returns, then provide a ```?callback=test``` added on to the URL and see if the output is correctly wrapped inside a call to ```test( )```. I'm hoping this makes sense!

Comment: I have implemented the solution you provided in your answer, and I have checked so that the if statement is true if providing callback to the url. However, when I'm manually open the url in the browser, including ?callback=test the output is exactly the same as without ?callback=test. Strange...

Comment: Have you included something akin to the ternary statement on the last line of the snippet? It's that line which is responsible for sending the output wrapped up - the if block itself simply prepares it!

Answer (score 20):

Yep, this is definately a cross-domain issue. But don't fret, there's two solutions to this problem.

#### Using JSONP

You can implement support for JSONP (JSON with padding) on the server (i.e. [Fergus Morrow's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893361/#13893673)). JSONP works cross-domain out-of-the-box and is basically JSON padded with a function call.

In your `.ajaxSetup` set `dataType` to `jsonp` and then on the server-side you should make sure to check for an url parameter named `callback` in the request. If that parameter is set, the JSON response has to be padded accordingly.

```
parseThis({ "json": "can", "be": "put", "in": "here" });
```

The above assumes `callback` is set to `parseThis`. jQuery will per default generate a function name, but you can override this by setting the value of `jsonpCallback` in your `.ajaxSetup`.

You can also use a shortcut to tell jQuery that you are requesting JSONP by just adding `?callback=?` to the request url.

#### Using Access-Control-Allow-Origin

An alternate solution is to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The above will allow **any** resource to use the service cross-domain. Read up on the article linked below for more information on how to configure `Access-Control-Allow`.

---

If you want to know more on Access-Control-Origin and CORS I recommend [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: Please don't downvote without commenting on why. I have no idea on how to improve my answer if I don't know what's wrong with it :(

Comment: I added a +1 because you also explained the ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` header in your post; you had +2 when I last looked! :/

Comment: @FergusMorrow The same person who upvoted for some reason changed and downvoted instead. Might have been a mistake, but I'd like to know. Thanks for your upvote ;)

Comment: * theoretically adds all origins, but many setups require the exact origin (say for example, localhost) to allow proper CORS.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it in a very easy way, by adding the following header to my server code (php):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: The kind of answer I like to find on SO.

Comment: don't use *. it allows everyone to access the script. instead use the actual domain you want to allow

Answer (score 3):

If it's an ASP.NET WEB application then you can also put this in your Global.aspx:

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Answer (score 3):

More PHP header settings

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

Good Luck