# Setting session variable in php through jquery click event

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

So I have been looking at all possible answers so far on Stackoverflow. But no matter how I try, I can't get this to work.

I'm trying to set a sessionvariable according to a clicked linked.

this can be 'grid' or 'list'

I can change the class, and the view of the corresponding div. However, my $.post call to php is not passing the variable ( im assuming this, since nothing happens ) or my php call is wrong.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<li class="display-control-list-item" > <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="js-set-display list" id="list" > Listview </a> </li>
<li class="display-control-list-item" > <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="js-set-display grid" id="grid" > Gridview </a> </li>
```

JQUERY

```
 function set_display_type( type ) {
   if ( type == 'grid' ) {
     $( '.js-set-display.list' ).removeClass( 'active' );
     $( '.js-set-display.grid' ).addClass( 'active' );
     $( '.content-inner' ).attr({ 'class' : 'container content-inner gridview' });
     var view = 'gridview';
     $.post( 'library/fx.behaviour.php' , { setdisplay: view });
   }
   if ( type == 'list' ) {
     $( '.js-set-display.grid' ).removeClass( 'active' );
     $( '.js-set-display.list' ).addClass( 'active' );
     $( '.content-inner' ).attr({ 'class' : 'container content-inner listview' });
     var view = 'listview';
     $.post( 'library/fx.behaviour.php' , { setdisplay: view });
   }
 }
```

and my PHP in fx.behaviour.php

```
$_SESSION[ 'display' ] = 'listview'; // set default
if ( $_POST[ 'setdisplay' ] != '' ) {
  $view = $_POST[ 'setdisplay' ];
  $_SESSION[ 'display' ] = $view;
}
```

In short: the sessionvariable won't update after clicking the url and passing the value through jquery to php.

Comment: and try to unset your $_SESSION variable before set it again

Comment: i think that's where my problem is. the variables aren't received in php. if I would try to just do

$_SESSION[ 'display' ] = $_POST[ 'setdisplay' ];

nothing is changing. but setting the default like above is working

Comment: try to print_r($_POST) in your php to see what your post array has

Comment: it prints an empty array. so that's clear :)
i tried passing the variables through an $.ajax call, but same result

Comment: and if you don't receive any variable check your path on `jQuery`, remember if the `php` file is on a folder outside you `jQuery` execution file you need to add `../` at the beginning of your `php` file path at `jQuery` `$.post()` definition

Comment: just like `$.post( '../library/fx.behaviour.php' , { setdisplay: view });`

Comment: jquery file is in assets/script/
php file is in library/

tried setting the path as the whole url, but didnt work

Comment: check if your jquery variable `view` is set with `alert(view);` after each `var view = '';` variable definition

Comment: getting the correct value in the alert

Comment: ok so your problem is the path

Comment: I think so too. I removed my htaccess from the directory, thought it might have something to do with restrictions in the rewriterule, but no change.
Im using the full path to the file now in the jquery ( http://www. someurl .nl/ ), pasted it in the browser to check it and it's working there

Comment: tried to do it with an ajax call to php again
got an error:

Origin URL is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do (cut some code out for quickness):

HTML (you don't require javascript void code if using jQuery):

```
<ul id="set-display">
    <li><a href="" id="list">Listview</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="grid">Gridview</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#set-display a').click(function(e) {
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    var view = (type === 'grid') ? 'gridview' : 'listview';
    $.post('library/fx.behaviour.php', { display: view });

    // you can use the view or type variable to trigger your other code
});
```

PHP:

```
session_start(); // if not called already

// if POST display not empty and is expected string then use it, otherwise default to 'listview'
$_SESSION['display'] = ( ! empty($_POST['display']) && in_array($_POST['display'], array('listview', 'gridview'))) ? $_POST['display'] : 'listview';
```

I used `$_POST['display']` rather than `setdisplay` for naming consistency. It might also be worth checking your jQuery call gets a valid 200 response. In Chrome you can do this by going to the Inspector, selecting the network tab, click the button, and watch for the request.

Comment: the call to fx.behaviour.php is 200 OK with the following url query:
http://www.branded89.nl/projects/mvc/library/fx.behaviour.php?callback=jQuery19107682344587519765_1367278981802&setdisplay=gridview&_=1367278981803

the variables are in there "setdisplay=gridview"

Comment: your method worked! I had to give in on making it into a function, and just call the ajax-call in the click event. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try to include your php into the jQuery file (just to test) and echo something `echo 'Foobar';` and in your jQuery execution file add `<?php include('../library/fx.behaviour.php');` and try changing the directory in the include line

## UPDATE

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893361/access-control-allow-origin-localhost)

Comment: tried putting the jsonp php parse code in my php code, and added the headers, but no results so far :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have {} when accessing string within scope of function:

```
function set_display_type( type ) {
   if ( type == 'grid' ) {
     $( '.js-set-display.list' ).removeClass( 'active' );
     $( '.js-set-display.grid' ).addClass( 'active' );
     $( '.content-inner' ).attr({ 'class' : 'container content-inner gridview' });
     var view = 'gridview';
     $.post( 'library/fx.behaviour.php' , setdisplay: view );
   }
   if ( type == 'list' ) {
     $( '.js-set-display.grid' ).removeClass( 'active' );
     $( '.js-set-display.list' ).addClass( 'active' );
     $( '.content-inner' ).attr({ 'class' : 'container content-inner listview' });
     var view = 'listview';
     $.post( 'library/fx.behaviour.php' , setdisplay: view );
   }
 }
```