# Passing variable from tinymce to jbimages

Tags: tinymce-4

I'm trying to pass variable from tinyMCE to jbimages. What i have is:

```
tinymceInstance = tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#desc",
    theme: "modern",
    skin: "light",
    relative_urls: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 300,
    relative_urls: false,
    plugins: [
         "link image preview hr anchor pagebreak ",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code nonbreaking",
         "directionality textcolor jbimages"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link image jbimages | print preview media fullpage | forecolor | spellchecker", 
    myVariable: 12345
 });
```

jbimages is a plugin to upload images. In config.php file in jbimages
I have the following code that is executed:

```
$config['img_path'] = '/images'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

How to retrieve variable myVariable from tinyMCE and use it in config.php. I tried a few things that I found on the web, but nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to pass it trough a session variable using jQuery. Your tinymce runs on client side (your computer) while php runs on the server.
Take a look at this question and answers. You might find what your looking for there:
[Setting session variable in php through jquery click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289484/setting-session-variable-in-php-through-jquery-click-event)